# Place div between two div without manipulating DOM or using z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

I have a bunch of `div.page` with `position: fixed` and I want to put a semitransparent `div#overlay` between `Element n` and the others. Furthermore, the number of divs is unknown and can **change**. And the overlay must always be between the topmost div and the others.

```
<div class="page">Element 1</div>
<div class="page">Element 2</div>
...
<div class="page">Element n</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>
```

I know that I can:

1. manipulate the DOM or
2. apply `z-index` to each div to put `div#overlay` in place

Neither seems really clean. Is there another option?

PS: Since I have to animate the opacity of `div#overlay`, I cannot use `:after`

Comment: Why isn't `z-index` clean?

Comment: and how come the need to animate div#overlay prevents you from using a pseudo-element??

Comment: DOM manipulation and `z-index` are perfect for this job. This question is crippled with unfounded prejudices...

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman `z-index` is unclean because the number of divs is unknown. I guess I'd have to write some JS to set the `z-index`, which is what I meant by unclean. Or do you see another way?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini I have to change the opacity with a swiping gesture (-> touchmove's pageX), and as far as I know that's not possible with pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1):

I actually had to do this very same thing just the other day. This is what I went with (adapted to your solution):

HTML:

```
<div id="stack">
    <div class="page">Element 1</div>
    <div class="page">Element 2</div>
    ...
    <div class="page">Element n</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#stack {
    position: fixed;
    top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
#stack > * {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
#stack > :last-child {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

This way, it's always the "topmost" element on the overlay stack that gets the semitransparent background. The limitation here is that you can only use a solid color background, since you're relying on the alpha component of the background color instead of the `opacity` property to achieve semitransparency.

Comment: Thanks, @máté. However, I need the overlay to always stay between Element n and the others, not on top of Element n (if I understand you solution correctly)

Comment: @TonaldDrump In this solution, the role of the overlay is fulfilled by the background color of the topmost `<div>` in the stack. So there is no separate `<div id="overlay">`

Comment: Interesting solution, I have given this a try, but I don't think this is quite what I need. I need the top div to have a non-transparent white background and then an overlay layer between this and the others.